# Low picture/image quality when capture from camera

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have one problem. When I try to get picture from camera, the quality is very low.
At first, capture the picture using camera, than save to the directory and at the same time get that picture and show in my app.The picture saved inside directory is a fine quality but when I get it from directory, the quality is low. below is my sample code :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

        if (g==1)
        {
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img5);
            myImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            View a = findViewById(R.id.img5);
            a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            byteArray1 = stream.toByteArray();
        }
}
```

any solution/suggestion?
Thanks :)

**Solved**

The problem solved when I follow the code given by [Antrromet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451951/antrromet) below

Comment: I don't see you getting the photo from the directory anywhere? All I see is you use the bundled thumbnail, which, by the way, is prone to errors as in my experience not all devices actually return any "data" extra. The thumbnail will obviously not have the same size as the 'full' picture on your storage medium.

Comment: actually I call thecamera using this: 
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

what is your suggestion then to avoid the error?and how to get the actual size of picture?
Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Best approach is probably to [supply the output path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7529603/1029225) with the `Camera` intent. Alternatively you could also implement [your own photo capture logic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855261/1029225) (more work), or possibly use a [`FileObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) on the DCIM/Camera directory.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.now I understand how its work :)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I have used the following code and this works perfectly fine for me.

```
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
            imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

and also

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

        case PICTURE_RESULT:
            if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);    
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

and

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: The above code works but somehow in OnActivityResult() -> the imageUri is shown null sometimes even though I've set imageUri while starting CameraActivity. @Antrromet

Comment: ^ [SOLVED] -> declared the imageUri and ContentValues in the onCreate() method rather than onClick listener :D

Comment: cannot understand the use of -  imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);   ?

Comment: Not working in Android 7.0.
Checkout this: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: @Antrromet any solution for Android N7.0?

Comment: it takes too much time as the images size goes upto 14mb

Comment: It is recommended to use this function "getRealPathFromURI" on Ui Thread, because it is a query to media store database. It might cause an ANR.

Comment: Anyone can enlighten me about the `imageurl` ?  It is used as `imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);` but not used anywhere else

Comment: Working!! Thanks

Comment: Whats imageLocationUri = getRealPathFromURI(imageLocationUri);

Answer (score 5):

I will give you something that work for me. I asked the same !

[Solution to save a picture in a specific folder without lost quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730189/how-can-i-save-a-picture-in-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-without-lo)

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

//**Create a new folder code:**

```
 String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) + "/your_name_folder";
            try {
                File ruta_sd = new File(path);
                File folder = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), nameFol);
                boolean success = true;
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    success = folder.mkdir();
                }
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Carpeta Creada...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Carpetas", "Error al crear Carpeta a tarjeta SD");
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();//agregue este
```

//**Method to take a Picture**

```
public void clickFoto(View view) {
        takePic();
    }
```

//***takePic()***

```
 private void takePic() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        *File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/your_name_folder/a" + "/photo_" + timeStamp + ".png");*
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
    }
```

//***onActivityResult***

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                            imgFoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                            imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
```

// ***getRealPathFromUri***

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: In `takePic()` you accidentally added an asterisk and also u forgot `Uri imageUri;`.

Answer (score -1):

**Add the photo to a gallery**
.
.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

for more detail : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE }