# Camera API - Image too small

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-camera-intent

I am trying to take a photo using the Camera API to populate into the imageview. The problem now is that the image taken from the camera is way too small to fill in the imageview.

This is the code i used to intent to the camera and get the image populated into the imageview.

```
btn_takeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_takeImage);
        btn_takeImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        });
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 0:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    img_backgroundImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                }
        }
    }
```

and this is my xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_additionalImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Did i do something wrong with the camera intent or something wrong with my xml?

Answer (score 4):

This is because the intent data always return the thumbnail of the captured image not the actual image.

To get actual image you have to do some tricky thing as follow.

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377783/low-picture-image-quality-when-capture-from-camera)

Comment: I gave it a try and it did worked. However, it only allows me to take photo and push the image in landscape even if i took the photo in portrait. There was also a outofmemoryerror exception when i took the photo a few times to test.

Comment: this is android bug. for orientation you have to check that is the height if retrieved bitmap is more then the width then rotate the image in 270 degree else leave it as it is.

Comment: When you use a ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, the image may be huge, and cause out-of-memory when decoded to bitmap. You can use BitmapFactory to reduce memory requirements, but in the end you may be better served if you control the camera yourself.