# How to set the size and quality of a picture taken with the android camera?

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop, image-quality

I wrote this code that takes a picture with the camera then converts it to a jpeg file and uploads it to Parse.com as a ParseFile.

The problem is that the picture is really small (153 x 204 px) and really low quality.

I need the picture to be at least 5 MP quality and to crop it to 300x300 px.

Here is the code I use til now.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_picture);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        byte[] image_byte_array;
              ParseObject post_object = new ParseObject("Gallery");
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            image_byte_array = stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile picture_file = new ParseFile("Picture.jpg", image_byte_array);
            picture_file.saveInBackground();
            post_object.put("photo", picture_file);
            post_object.saveInBackground();
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382217/609782)

> A camera intent return a thumbnail by default, so you need to
>   fetch the full image.

Derek's solution is right, but you have to improve it.

the real juice lies in fetching the full image which happens here -

```
thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
```

full path will be given by `getRealPathFromURI()`.

Comment: thank you , Ill select your answer as the right one , because the answer you linked helped me , thanks ;)

Comment: A tip - Try to google a bit more. In android, unless it is a very new API; all the question have been answered already. Such a great support base for us :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the link below

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image

You have to add a `Uri` which is the Uri of file to store the photo

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
```

a full sample

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_picture);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV);

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to save the picture to my phone storage, I just need it to be uploaded directly to the Parse.com server with the code that I have shown, so if you have any idea I would appreciate it to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: By using Camera Intent, you cannot avoid saving the picture to storage. If you really want to skip saving to storage, you have to implement your own camera.

Comment: The `data` returned in `onActivityResult` is only a thumbnail, that's why it is so small.

Comment: ok thank you , the answer that @Darpan linked helped me a lot , still thanks ;)