# display the photo captured from camera or after selecting it from gallery on another activity in imageview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm doing a photo editor app in android and I have two image buttons(one for the camera and the other for gallery). When I capture the photo with the camera or select the photo from the gallery I want the photo to be displayed in another activity on image view. I just wrote some of the code for the camera,but it doesn't work. If someone can help me , I'll be very grateful. I'm a newbie to programming.

manifest.xml

```
<manifest ..>
<uses-feature android:name = "android.hardware.camera"  android:required="false"/>
```

first activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private static int IMG_RESULT = 1;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton take_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    ImageButton get_photo  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);
    take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

        }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowPhotoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage",bitmap);`
        startActivity(intent);`
```

second activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_photo);
          ImageView showPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
          Bitmap bitImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
          showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitImage);
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Does your camera open? Are you able to capture the image. Any log errors?

Comment: the camera opens, i can capture the image,but it doesnt show it in another activity in imageview.

Comment: Please can you post the xml of the second activity you want to open the image, i want to see the `<ImageView>`

Comment: Yes,sure ..<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.ShowPhotoActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Your code works fine. remove the single quotation in here ` intent.putExtra("BitmapImage",bitmap);`
        startActivity(intent);``

Comment: Thats just a mistake I made when i copied the code...anyway,thank you . if you have any suggestion how to get the photo from gallery and do the same thing like with the camera image,I'll be very grateful :)

Comment: please let me know if the below answer works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code tested and works fine.

Add this on **manifest file**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

**First Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowPhotoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage",bitmap);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
ImageView showPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitImage);
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you..It works now,but when the photo is displayed in imageview is blurred..

Comment: Check the answer to avoid low quality image in [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377783/low-picture-image-quality-when-capture-from-camera)

Comment: Please mark it as an answer or upvote if it worked for you (y)