# Poor image clarity Android camera

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am using this code...

```
   iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent cameraIntent ;

                    cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


            }
        });

      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            iv.setImageBitmap(picture); 
        }
}
```

The Image that store to bitmap is very poor clarity. Only 4kb. How can i increase the clarity of the image ?

Comment: You got this because you get thumbnail image of picture for getting complete image look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10382217/4684984 also read https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: try this tutorial https://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this line

```
 cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
```

see official doc [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)